# ng build --prod not working on Docker container

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I am trying to deploy a MEAN stack application on a Docker container. The code for the MEAN stack application is at https://github.com/shivkiyer/quicknoteapp

I created a Docker file for the image:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y curl

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential checkinstall libssl-dev

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get update

RUN npm -v

RUN npm cache clean -f && \
    npm install -g @angular/cli

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4 && \
    echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list && \
    apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils && \
    apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata

RUN apt-get install debconf-utils

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mongodb-org

EXPOSE 8080 4200
```

The Docker image is built OK. I create a container with:
docker container run -it --name meanstack2 --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/home/mean --publish 4200:4200 meanstack

Since I gave my image a tag of meanstack. In the interactive mode, I create the /data/db directory needed by MongoDB. I start Mongo with the command "mogod &". I run npm install in both the Node JS and Angular directories.

Now the problem starts. When I try to do "ng build --prod" in the Angular CLI directory blog-frontend, I get all kinds of weird errors. When I do "ng build", it works perfectly OK and I am able to view the app on my browser after doing npm start in the Node Js directory "blog-backend".

Why doesn't --prod work? These are the errors I get:

```
ERROR in ng:///home/mean/blog-frontend/src/app/login-register/login-register.component.html (19,36): Property 'onLogin' does not exist on type 'LoginRegisterComponent'.
ERROR in ng:///home/mean/blog-frontend/src/app/login-register/login-register.component.html (85,42): Property 'resisterUser' does not exist on type 'LoginRegisterComponent'.
ERROR in ng:///home/mean/blog-frontend/src/app/welcome-page/welcome-page.component.html (35,38): Property 'onLogin' does not exist on type 'WelcomePageComponent'.
ERROR in ng:///home/mean/blog-frontend/src/app/note/note-form/note-form.component.html (89,15): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
ERROR in ng:///home/mean/blog-frontend/src/app/note/note-form/note-form.component.html (95,15): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
ERROR in /home/mean/blog-frontend/src/app/shared/topics.service.ts (10,33): Property 'configSettings' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; baseURL: string; }'.
ERROR in /home/mean/blog-frontend/src/app/shared/sub-topics.service.ts (12,33): Property 'configSettings' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; baseURL: string; }'.
ERROR in /home/mean/blog-frontend/src/app/shared/note.service.ts (14,33): Property 'configSettings' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; baseURL: string; }'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag `--prod` includes Angular AOT compilation and it has some restrictions of how we need to write code.

1) ***login-register.component.html (19,36): Property 'onLogin' does not
 exist on type 'LoginRegisterComponent'.***

It means that the template defines `onLogin` method but you didn't define it on [LoginRegisterComponent](https://github.com/shivkiyer/quicknoteapp/blob/master/blog-frontend/src/app/login-register/login-register.component.ts) class.

```
export class LoginRegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  onLogin() { <== must be here
  }
```

2) **login-register.component.html (85,42): Property 'resisterUser' does not exist on type 'LoginRegisterComponent'**

the same as above:

```
export class LoginRegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  onLogin() {
  }

  resisterUser() { <== add this
  }
```

3) **note-form.component.html (89,15): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.**

In `note-form.component.html` you call `addText` method without parameters:

```
(click)="addText()"
```

while in component you [defined](https://github.com/shivkiyer/quicknoteapp/blob/8521053a1fa5ffae753b1964c0428edcc408c125/blog-frontend/src/app/note/note-form/note-form.component.ts#L78) this method with required parameter `textValue`

```
addText(textValue: any) {
  ...
}
```

To fix it just make it optional

```
addText(textValue?: any) {
  ...
}
```

4) **note-form.component.html (95,15): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.**

The same with `addCode`

template:

```
(click)="addCode()"
```

component:

```
addCode(codeValue: any) {
  ...
}
```

Fix:

```
addCode(codeValue?: any) {
  ...
}
```

5) **Property 'configSettings' does not exist on type.**

This error has nothing to do with AOT but rather with Angular CLI restriction.

Shape of your production config should match the shape of development config.

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  configSettings: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:4200/api'
  }
};
```

with the config above you have to define production config with the same properties but you have:

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseURL: '/api'
};
```

Solution:

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  configSettings: {
    baseURL: '/api'
  }
};
```

Comment: Solved the problem! Thank you.

Comment: @yurzui Can some one tell how can I log this --prod errors of command line into a file?